# Mysql messages system - how query?

Tags: mysql, system, message

I work on my tiny messages system on MySQL.

I have the table "con":

```
id | user1 | user2
1  |   1   |   3
2  |   3   |   5
3  |   2   |   3
4  |   5   |   8
```

On, example logged user id = 3.

I want get from table user's id which user_id = 3 is talking.

Correct result for user id = 3:

```
id | user_id
1  | 1
2  | 5
3  | 2
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the `where` and with a condition in the `select`:

```
select id,
       (case when user1 = 3 then user2 else user1 end) as user
from con
where 3 in (user1, user2);
```

This only requires one pass over the table.

Answer (score 0):

Select the two groups of results (user1 = 3 and user2 = 3) and merge them together using `UNION`.

```
SELECT id, user1 AS user_id
FROM con
WHERE user2 = '3'

UNION

SELECT id, user2 AS user_id
FROM con
WHERE user1 = '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.user1 AS user_id FROM con a WHERE user2 = 3
UNION
SELECT b.id, b.user2 AS user_id FROM con b WHERE user1 = 3
```